# React-Admin create resource depend on another data

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Can't find how to that in the docs.

I need to add Create component for Posts.

Posts resource looks like this:

```
{
  title: string,
  content: string,
  date: Date,
  groupName: string,
  groupLevel: string
}
```

so Title, Content, Date are just simple inputs. however, the group data should come from another api request like **api.external.com/data/find/group** with some payload.
I need to show this groupName and GroupLevel on the screen but in disable inputs. and they should be part of the post object.

Comment: You could use a reference input. That can pull data from another resource (group). Not sure why you would want it disabled though. If a user can’t select the option then why is it a field?